# cassandra backup restore to another cassandra instance

Tags: database, backup, cassandra, restore

I have created a keyspace named XYZ in one cassandra instance.I made a copy of all data base file and pasted in another cassandra instance running in another system.When I access XYZ keyspace in that system it throws Exception like ***XYZ keyspace not found***.I ***pasted all*** the ***commit log ,saved caches files*** too in that system. Anything else should I make to access XYZ keyspace in that system.I have no clue to resolve this problem.Am expecting best suggestion as soon as possible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyspace and columnfamily don't magically spring into existence by the presence of data files, you need to create them in the target cluster too.  You can use "show schema" with the cli on the source cluster if you don't have that in source control.